# Grails 2.4.4 spring security role doesn't apply to user

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security, spring-annotations

I have controller:

```
class AdminController {

    def springSecurityService

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
    def index() {
        render "test";
    }
```

And user with role ROLE_ADMIN in the table:
[image]

But, when I use:
springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()
There is only one role: ROLE_NO_ROLES

Why?

def loggedInUser = springSecurityService.currentUser; returns correct user.

Config:
...

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = '...'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = '...'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = '...'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.groupAuthorityNameField = 'authorities'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRoleGroups = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
```

Thank you.

Comment: How did you resolve this error? What was the cause?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spring Security has an default UserDetailsService, which assigned the Roles to an User.

You could debug it to see what going wrong.

Or You create your own:
https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html

HTH